# how to plot triangular fuzzy membership graphic with the matlab code

Tags: matlab

```
fisMat=newfis('ex5_2');
fisMat=addvar(fisMat,'output','service',[0 10]);
fisMat=addmf(fisMat,'ouput',1,'low','trapmf',[0 0 5 15]);
fisMat=addmf(fisMat,'ouput',1,'middle','trimf',[5 15 25]);
fisMat=addmf(fisMat,'ouput',1,'high','trapmf',[15 25 30 30]);

rulelist=[1 1 1 1;2 2 1 1];
fisMat=addrule(fisMat,rulelist); 
subplot(3,1,2);plotmf(fisMat,'output',1);xlabel('tip');ylabel('output');
```

it can not show the fuzzy membership graphic when running the code.why?

Answer (score 0):

In the input range you specify [0,10], but the real range in each MF is [0,30]. Also you need to provide it with some input. If you just give the output, you will receive this message:

`No Input Variable yet`

Also the rule you defined is showing that you have 1 input:

```
rulelist=[1 1 1 1;2 2 1 1];
```

but you didn't specify it yet.

The following code works well:

```
FISX=newfis('new');
FISX=addvar(FISX,'input','d',[0 1]);
FISX=addmf(FISX,'input',1,'G','gaussmf',[0.05 0] );   
FISX=addmf(FISX,'input',1,'N','gaussmf',[0.15 0.25]); 
FISX=addmf(FISX,'input',1,'F','gauss2mf', [0.15 0.6 0.1 1.1]);
plotmf(FISX,'input',1)
FISX=addvar(FISX,'output','F',[-1 1]);
FISX=addmf(FISX,'output',1,'F','trimf',[0 1 2]);
FISX=addmf(FISX,'output',1,'S','trimf',[-1 0 1]);
FISX=addmf(FISX,'output',1,'B','trimf',[-2 -1 0]);
plotmf(FISX,'output',1)
XruleList=[
    1 1 1 1
    2 2 1 1
    3 3 1 1
    ];

FISX=addrule(FISX,XruleList);
```